# Is there a way in JavaScript to detect whether files can be dropped on the used device?

Tags: javascript

I created a form on a website that allows users to upload files. Users can also drag and drop files onto this form. However, on some devices, it is simply not possible to drag and drop *files* (e.g. on my iPhone). So I only want to display the text "Drag and drop files here" only on devices on which it makes sense.

Is there a way to detect whether the device supports drag and drop files in principle? A workaround could be to detect if a mouse pointer is moving. In this case, I would guess it is possible to drag and drop files. However, it would only be a guess.

Is there a more suitable way to detect this? Please note that I don't want to detect if the browser supports drag and drop in general, but if the browser supports drag and drop *files*.

Comment: Please note when questions are duplicates you should edit to clarify (not just a "banner" of meta content) rather than re-posting.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It's hard to understand what I should do when there is only a hint that my question is closed and that it is already answered, even it was definitly not.

I thought my question was clear enough, because my last sentence explicitly says that I'm not looking for general drag and drop support. I don't understand how I can be more clear. I do not understand why I am pointed to an answer that I am specifically not looking for.

And I saw no way to ask anyone and there was no description what I should do. That feels not nice.

Comment: However, so  you mean I should edit my old question, right? And I should edit it in a way that it's even more clear what I mean, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed it's now been reopened. If you have further queries, you can always see [meta].

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. It is good to know that there is a platform for such cases. I'll keep this in mind. Thank you again and have a great time.